# I installed Django version over 2.x but the command django-admin startproject(lowercase) make project with 1.x version

Tags: django, django-2.1

```
python3 -m venv venv
source venv/bin/actvaite # activate virtual env
pip install --upgrade pip
pip3 install Django # Django 2.1.7 installed

django-admin startproject temp # 1.x version
Django-admin startproject temp # 2.x version
```

1. django-admin vs Django-admin
   django-admin start with lowercase make project 1.x version
   Django-admin start with uppercase make project 2.x version

2. offical docs - start with lowercase
   [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/intro/tutorial01/)

summary
1) whats wrong in my environment?
2) how can i make project with django-admin(lowercase)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the `pip` command is pointing to Python 2.x, and `pip3` is pointing to Python 3.x. To see if this is this case:

```
deactivate  # in case you're in a virtual environment
pip --verison
pip3 --verison
```

This will show you which version of Python each one points to. Since Django 2.x is only compatible with Python 3, `pip` will automatically installed Django 1.11.x if you're installing with `pip` under Python 2.x.

The best way around this is to ensure you're using a virtual environment. To start a new Django project:

```
python3 -m venv my_project_venv
. my_project_venv/bin/activate
pip --version  # Make sure it is pointing to Python 3
pip install django
django-admin startproject my_project
```

The next time you come back to work on your project, you can re-activate the virtual environment with everything you've pip installed inside it:

```
. my_project_venv/bin/activate
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Did you install Django in your environment?

```
pip install Django
```

A quick workaround is running the following in your environment:

```
python3 venv/bin/django-admin startproject temp
```